# When there are no chat flags, hide the flag count

Tags: bug, flags, chat

I have chat open all day and every once in a while I come back to it to see this:

[image]

Oh, wow, a flag! Let's click on it!

[image]

Oh, okay, no flag for me :( So I close the bubble, but the flag counter stays there for me to repeat this process over and over again until I refresh my browser window.

I understand that the flag count isn't being reset when someone else handles the flag, but at least it could be hidden once I got an empty flag list from the server.